# Openvpn configure ignore mask setting on server

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I am setting up a Windows OpenVPN server. I am able to connect, but I cannot ping the server.

Here is my server.conf:

```
port 1194 
proto tcp 
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem

push "route 10.19.0.0 255.255.0.0"
server 10.19.0.0 255.255.0.0

keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
max-clients 10
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3

client-to-client
duplicate-cn
```

Here is the log of setting up the server:

[image: OpenVPN log with a red box added around "10.19.0.1/255.255.255.252"]

I found where the problem is. The server is configured with the wrong mask:

[image: Network Connection Details window showing IPv4 address "10.19.0.1", IPv4 Subnet Mask "255.255.255.252", IPv4 DHCP Server "10.19.0.2", etc.]

I have to configure the IP and mask manually so that I can ping the server:
[image: Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) Properties window showing manual setting of IP address "10.19.0.1", Subnet mask "255.255.255.0"]

But this config will overwrite by OpenVPN server in next reboot, than I have to do it again.

What did I set wrong on my server? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `topology subnet` to your server.conf

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)